# How to append a stdClass object with another stdClass object when both index are same?

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

How to append a stdClass object with another stdClass object when both index are same ?
for example I have 2 objects like below

```
 stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'monitors' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'monitor' => 
        array (
          0 => "www.1.com",
          1 => "www.2.com",
          2 => "www.3.com"
        )
   ));
));
```

and another object is

```
   stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'monitors' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'monitor' => 
        array (
          0 => "www.11.com",
          1 => "www.21.com",
          2 => "www.31.com"
        )
   ));

    ));
```

if i combine these two like following

```
$obj1->moniotors = $obj2->monitors;
```

indexing are getting replaced.

```
      0 => "www.1.com",
      1 => "www.2.com",
      2 => "www.3.com"
```

with element of obj2. i want contentiously `3,4,5`

```
      3 => "www.11.com",
      4 => "www.21.com",
      5 => "www.31.com" .
```

how can i do this?

Comment: You can't have 2 keys/indexes with the same value.

Comment: I want second obj should increase key automatically to 3,4,5

Comment: Well you need to say the magic word `Abrakadabra make 2 classes into one, and fix up all the inconsistancies` And then as if by magic it all gets done for you.

Comment: This is not standard class functionality, if you need a class that does this all you have to do write one.

Comment: I have done it @RiggsFolly . i did magic in my code lol

Comment: Well please publish how you did it as an answer to this question. Then we can all share in the knowledge, and specifically those that find this question and want to know how you solved it. Its perfectly legal to accept you own answer. the important thing is that there is and answer.

Comment: I have just converted those objects into array then i merged it